# Google Places API does not work with an OR condition

Tags: ios, google-places-api

I have successfully queried Google Places API with IOS7 for both type and keyword searches. However I cannot seem to get an "OR' condition to work with keywords. The Google docs say to use the pipe | but that does not work.

For example, this search string works, searching for cafe AND espresso:

NSString *testKeywordSearch = @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=37.787930,-122.4074990&radius=5000&keyword=espresso+cafe&sensor=false&key=mykeyhere;

This does NOT work, searching for cafe OR espresso:

NSString *testKeywordSearch = @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=37.787930,-122.4074990&radius=5000&keyword=espresso|cafe&sensor=false&key=mykeyhere;

The app crashes with:
2014-02-27 18:52:11.663 GooglePlaces[10250:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'

Am I missing something really simple here?

Comment: It must be something in your app since I can run both queries from my browser (using my API key) and they both return results. Check your JSON return before you start parsing it to see what Google is returning you.

Comment: Yes, you can share your application code here. I am also getting all the json input from the places API.

Comment: Sadly, this website would not let me post an update (my code) through edit. It appears that the problem is NOT the google search, just as the two of you say. The problem is that the conversion of the search string to a url breaks with the pipe. NSURL *googleRequestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:andKeywordSearch];//this works with plus, returns nil with pipe. The pipe must be a special character requiring a delimiter even within an NSString.